# CouchDB Document Versioning

Tags: couchdb, versioning, mvcc

Hi I want to implement document versioning in my CouchDB database where every edits to the document will be recorded in terms of, what fields are changed, who did the change and when did the change happen.

Does any CouchDB engine provides this support or I have to handle it manually at client side?

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB's use of Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) is **not** a versioning system. It's a common misconception because of the word "Version" in the title, but the real purpose is "Concurrency Control".

In short, if you want this in your application, you will have to build it yourself.

Comment: In short, there are no commercial CouchDB engines that provides this functionality? Although I did saw some client libraries that perform the versioning in the background.